# How to edit a ListPreference value from java code in Android

Tags: android, listpreference

I know how to change the value of a `CheckBoxPreference`, but I can't get it to work for a `ListPreference`.

Here is how my preference screen is built:

- one `CheckBox` for the default
- A `ListPreference` to select a color other than the default.

The `ListPreference` is defined with the key "titleColor", as follows :

```
CharSequence[] entries = { "Dark grey", "Light grey", "Light red", "Red" };
CharSequence[] entryValues = { "#4c4c4c", "#b5b5b5", "#ab6a68", "#962622" };
final ListPreference color = (ListPreference) findPreference("titleColor");
color.setEntries(entries);
color.setEntryValues(entryValues);
```

Now, when I select a color I do this:

```
color.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            System.out.println("In the onClick method");
            System.out.println("change title color");
            Editor editor2 = defaultColor.getEditor();
            editor2.putBoolean("defaultColor", false);
            editor2.commit();
            return true;
        }

    });
```

And this seems to work, though I'm not sure to do this properly.

Now I have been trying to do something similar when I select the default color, but I can't get the list to either uncheck everything OR check a color that would be the default.

Any idea?

Comment: As far as I now the ListPreference works like a string value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of the `CheckBox`:

If you had a default color `CheckBox` it would be fixed using `android:dependency`, but since you don't have it, I guess that's the only way.

Related with the `ListPreference`, is quite similar:

```
ListPreference lp = (ListPreference)findPreference("listPreference_key");
lp.setValue("");
```

You can check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html) to know which methods are available.

Comment: I added the definition of my ListPreference, because I tried your code but although it works and I obtain no selection in the List, I tried to pass "Red" instead of "", and still got no selection... And I did read the docs before asking my question, that's because I didn't find that i asked it...

Comment: @Sephy: Remember you must pass an entry not a entryValue.

Comment: Ok my bad. I was doing it wrong. I was trying to get the color by its entry name ( which appeared to be the logic way for me, but apparently not.) I do have to give it the value and the List takes care of checking the right element for me. lp.setValue("#962622") to get the red. I'll let the empty string though.
Thanks for the help Macarse.